# Error installing php7.4 with brew on MacOS Sierra 10.12

Tags: macos, homebrew, php-7.4

I am trying to install php 7.4 on MacOS Sierra with

```
brew install php@7.4
```

After the warning saying macOS 10.12 is unsupported I get this error:

```
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - configure
```

`brew doctor` say:

```
Warning: Some installed kegs have no formulae!
This means they were either deleted or installed with `brew diy`.
You should find replacements for the following formulae:
  python@2

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  python@2

Warning: You are using macOS 10.12.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience while you are running this old version.
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Steps to fix

1. First step, and most important (unless you have a very good reason not to) : Upgrade macOS to the latest available version for your hardware. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#Hardware_compatibility
2. Run `brew link python@2`
3. Run `brew install php@7.4`

Comment: I cannot upgrade my system because of compatibility issues with other softwares.